# frequent linux mint hangs

Tags: linux, linux-mint, debugging, freeze

My Linux Mint system (17 Cinnamon, lenovo g565) hangs up frequently during work (say, 2-4 times a day).
It may look different

- white screen
- black screen
- screen freeze

Maybe some of these symtoms look familiar and you know possible reasons to check?
If not, what updates/logs/diagnostic tools can you advice to make the most systematic and direct search of the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start from the very beginning.  Go to /var/log and have a look at the syslog file.
Almost every error and problem will show up there.  Any error entry is a potential problem, it is either the result of another error or the primary cause of your issues.

A healthy system should have VERY few error entries in syslog.

Once you get a line on the problems you see, bring them back to the forum.  Someone here will probably know what is happening.

If you have no syslog file or it does not appear to be current, start the syslog daemon.
Have a look here if this is something you do not understand.

http://computernetworkingnotes.com/network-administrations/syslog-server.html

Comment: thanks for your answer!
Checking syslog after hangs brought me the same lines just before system hanged:
[pastebin](http://pastebin.com/wx3A2qhR) last are:
08:26:34 konst54-Lenovo-G565 wpa_supplicant[1069]: nl80211: send_and_recv->nl_recvmsgs failed: -33
08:28:32 wpa_supplicant[1069]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED

Comment: also I have some CPU temperature issues (noticed 75-82 C), but system hanged even after cpufreq powersavemode

Comment: created [a new question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175745/wpa-supplicant-nl80211-hangs-linux-mint-frequently)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the reasons, but complete uninstallation of compiz libraries somehow eliminated frequent hangs in my case.