# wpa_supplicant nl80211 hangs linux mint frequently

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, debugging, freeze, wpa-supplicant

My Linux Mint system (17 Cinnamon, lenovo g565) hangs up frequently during work (say, 2-4 times a day). It may look different - white screen, black screen, screen freeze. 
 Checking syslog after hangs brought me the same lines just before system hanged: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/wx3A2qhR), last are:

```
08:26:34 wpa_supplicant[1069]: nl80211: send_and_recv->nl_recvmsgs failed: -33
08:28:32 wpa_supplicant[1069]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED
```

I'm not 100% sure, that it it's the reason, but the pattern seems to be same with several hangs.
*Also I have some CPU temperature issues (noticed 75-82 C), but system hanged even after cpufreq powersave mode*.

What should I do to make more specific diagnosis and eliminate the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug, check [this launchpad bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wpa/+bug/1323089). There is only one suggestion offered to fix it, [message n.24](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wpa/+bug/1323089/comments/24):

> Oops this has been going on since 2009 and a developer did respond that it is simply for roaming in corporate environments with multiple access points to connect to. If you only have one AP at home go into network manager, select "Edit Connection", highlight your AP / wlan0 and click "Edit". Then click the down arrow next to BSSID which is blank. Then select the mac address that was hidden before.

Comment: That's not a *fix*, that's a *workaround*. Also, the developer probably meant that *the feature* is for roaming corporate environments, but what OP is talking about is *an apparent bug* in the implementation of the feature.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae, Actually I'd be completely satisfied with this workaround, as it eleminates my nl80211 error according to syslog. But the sad thing is that I'm still experiencing the hangs problem. So I'll create another question for it, and gratefully accept your answer.

Comment: created [new question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175964/linux-mint-hangs-how-to-find-a-reason)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the reasons, but complete uninstallation of compiz libraries somehow eliminated frequent hangs in my case.