# linux mint hangs - how to find a reason?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, logs, debugging, freeze

My Linux Mint system (17 Cinnamon, lenovo g565) hangs up frequently during work (say, 2-4 times a day). It usually looks like a white or black screen (or off if the lid was closed). CPU seems to be a bit hot during this (but I cleaned the fan yesterday in order to exclude overheat reasons, and it's about 50-55 C during normal work). Hotkeys do not take effect, and I just turn the power down.
Checking the syslog before hangs doesn't give me the specific repetitive pattern to check. But here is [some of it](http://pastebin.com/1c5EzwV5) (before hangs) anyway, and there is [some more before eleminating nl80211 issue](http://pastebin.com/wx3A2qhR).
Here are two more questions of mine around this problem - [first](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175322/frequent-linux-mint-hangs),[second](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175745/wpa-supplicant-nl80211-hangs-linux-mint-frequently).
UPD: It doesn't seem to be a user software problem - I left the station as it is after boot, and it still hanged in a few hours.
What should I do to make more specific diagnosis and eliminate the problem with  hangs? Any logs, diagnostic tools I should check?

Comment: The only error in syslog during boot is NetworkManager[1007]: <error> [1419585856.898333] [nm-dns-dnsmasq.c:396] update(): dnsmasq owner not found on bus: Could not get owner of name 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq': no such name. More lines here: http://pastebin.com/6zUMTLqF

Answer (score 0):

If system hangs when using SSD for Mint, try running a Live distro instead to see if disk is responsible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the reasons, but complete uninstallation of compiz libraries somehow eliminated frequent hangs in my case.